# Equivalent of feature:repo-add and feature:install in Apache Felix

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I am familiar of feature:repo-add and feature:install in Karaf. I am looking for similar thing in Apache Felix or any alternate way to do the same.

Comment: I would like to know more about your goals. Why do you want to use plain felix instead of karaf? Felix itself is only the OSGi framework it is not a complete solution for packaging your application.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, I have got a project where Felix is the requirement. I have developed the required application using Karaf and blueprint, everything is working fine, but due to project guideline I have to use Felix, I am new to OSGi and I am not sure if Felix is enough. So right now my App is ready but I am struggling deploying it on Felix. There are lot dependencies to be installed and Karaf's feature:install was able to install all dependent dependencies but I could not find anything like this in Felix.

Comment: Karaf uses felix as OSGi framework. So you could argue that you deploy on felix :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy on plain felix without karaf then I recommend using the bnd packaging.

It is used in the enroute tutorials (you need to switch to felix as they use equinox by default). You give it a repository of the bundles to draw from (pom file) and a bndrun file. The output is a runnable jar with all bundles and felix included. When looking at the bndrun ignore the runbundles .. you do not have to write them. Threy are automatically generated.

When deciding between karaf and bnd packaging keep in mind that you do not have the pre defined features of karaf. So finding the set of bundles for the repo is a bit more work. You can use the list of bundles from the karaf features you use as a good starting point.

See https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute/tree/master/examples/quickstart/app

Comment: Thanks Christian, will give it a try.